# PHP Array to Variables after Foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Hi My Code is the following

```
if(is_a($values, 'pingidentity\opentoken\helpers\multistringarray'))
{
     foreach($values->keySet() as $key) 
     {

          foreach($values->get($key) as $value) 
          {
               $i++;
               print "<tr><td class=\"d".($i&1)."\">".$value."</td><tr>";
          }
     }
}
```

When I `print_r` the array output is

```
pingidentity\opentoken\helpers\MultiStringArray Object
(
    [_values:pingidentity\opentoken\helpers\MultiStringArray:private] => Array
        (
            [not-before] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2014-06-13T19:33:15Z
                )

            [authnContext] => Array
                (
                    [0] => urn:oasis
                )

            [email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test@test.com
                )

            [subject] => Array
                (
                    [0] => usernametest
                )
        )
)
```

I'm looking for help on how to take the output of the array and input the values into variables

I've now did the followng to cast the object to array

$array = (array) $values;

with results as following

```
Array
        (
            [not-before] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2014-06-13T23:17:08Z
                )

            [authnContext] => Array
                (
                    [0] => urn:oasis                )

            [email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test@test.com
                )

            [subject] => Array
                (
                    [0] => usernametest
                )


        )

)
```

Comment: Why not just use associative arrays, i.e. `a['somename'] = 'x';` rather than numerically indexed `a[0] = 'x';`

Comment: You probably need to access each `$value` like `$value[0]` because of the way you have your object/array setup. A simple var_dump/print_r of `$value` would show you it's structure.

Comment: which values are you trying to access?

Comment: I'm tring to access all values with [0] = > ....... for [email], [subject] ..etc

Answer (score 0):

remember that you can access to the value of the key:

```
$result = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value){
  if($key != 'excludeVal' && $key != 'exclude2') //here you can exclude some keys that you don't need
  $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

after that you can use extract function

```
extract($result);
```

or even use `extract($values);`

this function return each key like a variable, eg: if you has a key named ["key1"] after the extract call you can use the variable $key1 and it has the value of the key

Comment: when I tried

$result = array();
    foreach($values as $key => $value){
      if($key != 'not-before' && $key != 'authnContext') //here you can exclude some keys that you don't need
      $result[$key] = $value;
      
     
    }
     extract($result);

no results were returned

Comment: there are not returned, you use the keys las variables, if you have a key that you don't exclude you could use it like variable, i mean if you dont exclude the key authnContext and you use the extract($result) function you'll be able to use the $authnContext variable

Comment: try to do this foreach($values as $key => $value){echo $key.": ".$value;}

Comment: I tried both suggestions and neither of them returned any results

Comment: what is the result that you obtained?

Comment: still not able to return data everything is returning null

Comment: ´foreach($values as $key){foreach($values[$key] as $key2){foreach($values[$key][$key2] as $key3 => $val3){ echo "values['".$key."']['".$key2."']['".$key3."']=".$val3."<br>";}}}´   the number of foreach depens of the dimensions in the array

Answer (score -1):

You can type cast this object to array.
OR use Object and use -> operator to access the content

Comment: can you provide assistance on how to do that?